# Spring boot not returning values from thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, web

I'm new to Spring boot Development and I'm trying to find out why my program isnt returning the values to html. I tried a lot of examples none worked. I would appreciate the help.

```
    @GetMapping("/produto/{description}")
public String getLike(Model model,@PathVariable("description") String description){
    List<Produto> produtos =  (List<Produto>) productService.findLike(description);
    model.addAttribute("produtos",produtos);
    System.out.println(produtos);
    return "redirect:/static/produtos.html";
}
```

And then try to redirect to this..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
 <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<tr th:each="produtos : ${produtos}">
<td><span th:text="${produtos.id}"></span></td>
<td><span th:text="${produtos.name}"></span></td>
<td><span th:text="${produtos.description}"></span></td>
<td><span th:text="${produtos.price}"></span></td>
</tr>

</html>
```

When instead of returning the model I return a list trough a json client it works and returns everything. But when it's a model. It doesnt work and returns this...

```
 redirect:/static/produtos.html
```

When i use get trough this.

```
http://localhost:8047/produto/lenco
```

But should return this in html

```
[
{
    "id": "223334455",
    "name": "lonco",
    "description": "lenco",
    "price": 83223
}
]
```

Comment: If you are using RestController annotation, returning string wouldn't take you to the page, but return the string as in your example. So if that is the case, try with the Controller annotation instead of RestController.

Comment: `Model` should to be after request & path variables

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with a redirect. On a redirect, your model attributes are lost.

You have a couple options.

1. Just return `/static/produtos.html`. A redirect doesn't make sense unless you're redirecting to another controller.
2. Use `RedirectAttributes` in your request method.

   ```
   public String getLike(Model model, @PathVariable("description") String 
      description, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
      List<Produto> produtos =  (List<Produto>)productService.findLike(description);
      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("produtos",produtos);
      return "redirect:/static/produtos.html";
   }
   ```